# Array modified without I ask him in C

Tags: c

I'm pretty new with C and I have the following question :

I have 2 array : `int tab[200],tab2[200]`

Then,I fill these two array like this :

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++) { 
   r = (rand() % (99 - 10 + 1) + 10)
   tab[i] = r;
   tab2[i] = r;
}
```

Then I print `tab2[0]` and I modify `tab` without modify `tab2`
And when I print `tab2[0]` again, it give antoher value than previsouly, why ?
But only with `tab2[0]`, with another index it work.

What changes I do on `tab` :

```c
for(i=0; i<200; i++) {
   if(tab[i] > tab[i+1]) {
      tmp = tab[i];
      tab[i] = tab[i+1];
      tab[i+1] = tmp;
}
```

And when I do `printf("%d",tab2[0]);` before this for loop and after this for loop, `tab2[0]` isn't the same

Comment: [Edit] and show a [mcve]. Read this: [ask]

Comment: The problem seems to be else where actually

Comment: My crystal ball is thinking that you're trying to modify `tab[i]` when your `for` loop has finished. The value of `i` will then be `200`, so you're writing 'out-of-bounds' in the `tab` array, and that's overflowing into the first element of the `tab2` array.

Comment: Compile your code with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code (with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) to get no warnings. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: Ok Adrien thanks you, I understand what is going on. I juste add `&& i+1 != 200` in the if condition and it works.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch mmh yes I do that and it doesn't give me any warnings ( before I made the changes )

Comment: Use not only `gdb` but perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and/or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: Why has the question been closed? It is very clear.

Comment: I will check this thanks

Comment: The question was unclear in 1st revision. I guess that's why it was closed.

Comment: Try starting loop at 1 and use `i-1` instead of `i+1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(i=0; i<200; i++) {
   if(tab[i] > tab[i+1]) {   //<<<<<<<<<<<<
      tmp = tab[i];
      tab[i] = tab[i+1];
      tab[i+1] = tmp;  //<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

on the last run of the loop, `i` is 199 and `i + 1` is 200, but the last valid index of `tab` is 199. You're reading and writing out of array bounds which results in undefined behaviour.

---

Now you'll ask: *"how is it possible that `tab2[0]` has been modified, I've never modified `tab2[0]"*.

The answer is: What you see here is a manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I clearly understand where the problem is. Thank you a lot